# Python: How to flash a single msg per input without activating all flash msg when only one input is wrong

Tags: python, html, flask

This is what I get when I type the not found code:
"ZZZ Not a valid code USD Not a valid code {value} Not a valid amount"
By just adding one wrong input I'm getting on all the others a flash msg as wrong, and I'm also not getting the number.
I have try to use if elif else and result is even worse.

I just added 'USD' code to the countries list and I got some progress, where I'm running in some issues is with amt_to_convert.

Input one 'convert_from' is using a value out of countries list.

Input two 'amt_to_convert' use the amout to be convert, wish is a number.

Input three 'convert_to' is using a value out of countries list.

> app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, session, flash, url_for
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates, CurrencyCodes
from decimal import Decimal


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "hakunamatata"

c = CurrencyRates(force_decimal=True)

countries = ['IDR', 'BGN', 'ILS', 'GBP', 'DKK', 'CAD', 'JPY', 'HUF', 'RON', 'MYR', 'SEK', 'SGD', 'HKD', 'AUD', 'CHF',
             'KRW', 'CNY', 'TRY', 'HRK', 'NZD', 'THB', 'EUR', 'NOK', 'RUB', 'INR', 'MXN', 'CZK', 'BRL', 'PLN', 'PHP', 'ZAR']


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home_page():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/result', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def convert_result():

    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            convert_from = (request.form.get('convert_from').upper())
            value = request.form.get('value')
            convert_to = (request.form.get('convert_to').upper())
            result = c.convert(convert_from, convert_to, Decimal(value))
            return render_template("result.html", convert_from=convert_from, convert_to=convert_to, value=result)

        except:
# The three following flash msg will flash all at ones, even when only one input is wrong

            if (convert_from not in countries):
                flash(f"{convert_from} Not a valid code")
                print('convertFom')

            if (convert_to not in countries):
                flash(f"{convert_to} Not a valid code")
                print('convertTo')

            if (not isinstance(value, float)):
                flash("{value} Not a valid amount")
                print('value')

            if (convert_from not in countries or convert_to not in countries or not isinstance(value, float)):
                return redirect(url_for('home_page'))

            else:
                # result = c.convert(convert_from, convert_to, Decimal(value))

                return render_template("result.html", convert_from=convert_from, convert_to=convert_to, value=result)
```

```
>home.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block title %}Currency Exchange{% endblock %}</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">

</head>

<body>

    {% for category,msg in get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
    <p class="{{category}}">{{msg}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        <form action="/result" method="POST">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Convert From" name="convert_from">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Amt" name="value">
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Convert To" name="convert_to">

                <button id="exchange">
                <span>&#8595;</span>
            </button>

                <div class="result">
                    <div class="rate" id="rate">{{your_rate}}</div>
                </div>

        </form>
        {% endblock %}


        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

```
>result.html

{% extends 'home.html' %} {% block title %}Currency Result{% endblock %} {% block content %}
<h2>You conveted from {{convert_from}}</h2>
<h2>In to {{convert_to}}</h2>
<!-- <h2>The amount of {{value}}</h2> -->
<h2>You will get {{value}}</h2>

<!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Home</button> -->
<a href="/" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Home</a> {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. To "explain yourself" better, please: 1) try writing something like "I have the following code:" followed by the code; 2) try writing something like "I got this error message:", followed by the error, formatted as code; 3) use full sentences to explain *what the code is supposed to do*, 4) explain how you tried to solve the problem yourself and why it didn't help; 5) ask a clear question ending with `?`; 6) **don't** write apologies or small talk.

Comment: You should also try to [create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem.

Comment: pls put the error trace log, seems like you are getting an exception on a certain input field.

Comment: I'm not getting a python error, what I'm is all the flash msg at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your error, it is reporting `ZZZ` and `USD` as invalid countries. This leads to the suspicion you are somehow passing `USD` as a country (either convert_from or convert_to). You should actually check you are entering the right value in one of those fields.

Also, I would rename the field `value` since `value` has a specific meaning in HTML and Forms (maybe call it `amt_to_convert`). Who knows, it might be interfering with your code

Also, you will definitely get an error for the amount because you are checking that it is a float value but your form will pass it as a string to Flask and you didn't convert the value immediately to float (you only convert the value while it is being passed to your convert function; you are not converting your stored variable).

Change your code to `value = float(request.form.get('value'))`

**Explanation:** You raise an error when value is not float, so you should convert the value from your form to float

Comment: I'm intentionally adding ZZZ to get just one flash msg for that particular input, but instead I'm also getting that USD is invalid, Now if I'm typing one of the countries with in forex-python list I will get the convert result, I'm trying to build a error handling with flash messages, is part of the requirement.

Comment: I change value to amt_to_convert, still same problem

Comment: I understand you are using ZZZ but your error is also reporting USD as an invalid country so I was saying to check you are not sending USD as a country instead of a currency. You don't have USD listed as a country. Can you try printing out the values of convert_from, convert_to, amt_to_convert, before you call the conversion function. Also edit your question and include the values for the 3 fields you are using for test.

Comment: I added 'USD' to the countries list, Thanks, didn’t see that, now the amt_to_convert wish is a number is the one causing problem

Comment: I've updated my answer. It should solve your problem now

Comment: Thanks @NoCommandLine, how can I get the flash msg to run if I'm not putting a number on amt_to_convert or if I leave it the input blank?

Comment: 1) I assume your convert function will fail if it has the wrong type of parameters including blank parameters. If so, then your current code will work. 2) Alternatively, you can move the tests from the ```except``` block to before you call the convert function. This means, you retrieve the values from the form, you check them. if any one fails, you return an error. If they all pass, you go ahead and call the convert function. The only downside with my current explanation is that the errors will be returned one by one, unless you modify the code (not enough space in comments to explain how)

Comment: Thank you so much, I have an idea of of your explanation, you have been really helpful